# AttributeError: module 'pyttsx3' has no attribute 'init' but i tried everything

Tags: init, pyttsx3

So i had a much bigger problem ,but i sorted that out. Now, i have this error command:

pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.7.9)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/danku/jarvis.py", line 16, in 
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
AttributeError: module 'pyttsx3' has no attribute 'init'

i tried kinda everything(installed pygame,pypiwin32,pywintypes) but i cant figure it out. Here is my beloved code (dont laugh its jarvis code):

```
#alap
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import pywhatkit
import pyjokes
import subprocess
import pywintypes
import win32com.client
import pygame 


engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def time():
    Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    speak(Time)

def date():
    year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    month = int(datetime.datetime.now().month)
    date = int(datetime.datetime.now().day)
    speak(date)
    speak(month)
    speak(year)

def wishme():
    speak("Welcome back sir! All system are ready for work!")
    speak("the current time is")
    time()
    speak("The current date is")
    date()
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if hour >= 6 and hour<12:
        speak("Good morning sir!")
    elif hour >=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good afternoon sir!")
    elif hour >=18 and hour<24:
        speak("Good evening sir!")
    else:
        speak("Good night sir!")

    speak("Jarvis at your service. Please tell me how can i help you?")

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
        print(query)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        speak("Say that again")

        return "none"
    return query

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wishme()
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()

        if 'wikipedia' in query:  #if wikipedia found in the query then this block will be executed
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2) 
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)
``
Also i'm using python 2.71, and latest of pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normally because you have named your Python file the same as the module you are importing and caused a circular reference. Try changing the name of your file. It should resolve the issue.